# Powershell change multiple users AD properties

Tags: powershell

Still learning Powershell for AD and i have one question that is bothering me. Have to change AD properties for multiple users in AD within specific location, for example we have in same OU people from Berlin and from Washington, and cities are set in each profile, but im wondering if i need to get also properties before changing address for one of those locations like this

```
Get-ADUser -filter 'City -like "Berlin"' -SearchBase 'OU=Users,OU=Staff,DC=Contoso,DC=com' -Properties StreetAddress, PostalCode | % {Set-ADUser $_ -Replace @{StreetAddress="New street 11";PostalCode="221202XX"}}
```

or if it would work also without doing -Properties and just pipe filter City results to Set-ADUser

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to specify `-Properties` unless you want to see them in the output. You also don't need the foreach, simply piping to `Set-ADUser` is sufficient.

```
Get-ADUser -filter 'City -like "Berlin"' -SearchBase 'OU=Users,OU=Staff,DC=Contoso,DC=com' |
    Set-ADUser $_ -Replace @{StreetAddress="New street 11";PostalCode="221202XX"}
```

This will update those values just fine. The same is true for filtering. The following command will filter on the postalcode but it will not be included in the output unless you add `-Properties postalcode`

```
Get-ADUser -Filter "PostalCode -eq '221202XX'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for answer, i have left out -Properties and that seems fine, also tried but this won't work without foreach as i guess Set-ADUser does not know which of those users that are filtered out needs to be updated. So i had to use

```
Get-ADUser -filter 'City -like "Berlin"' -SearchBase 'OU=Users,OU=Staff,DC=Contoso,DC=com' | % {Set-ADUser $_ -Replace @{StreetAddress="New street 11";PostalCode="221202XX"}}
```

while if i use without foreach

```
Get-ADUser -filter 'City -like "Berlin"' -SearchBase 'OU=Users,OU=Staff,DC=Contoso,DC=com' | Set-ADUser $_ -Replace @{StreetAddress="New street 11";PostalCode="221202XX"}
```

i get error

> Set-ADUser : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The argument is null. Provide a valid value for the
> argument, and then try running the command again.

but anyway, seems to be OK without -Properties which was my main concern

Comment: Without the ForEach-Object, remove th `$_`, since you are piping the user objects. This is a typo in @DougMaurer s answer